# raspberry 4 ssh not working for me

Tags: ssh, kali

I just bought raspberry 4 B, i am using kingstone 128gb sd card and stickyfingers (kali linux) as OS. I am trying to do headless ssh setup but it doesnt work. I tryied to put ethernet cable to it but it doesnt show nowhere (tryied to locate ip in router settings and with nmap). I added empty file with name "ssh" and .conf file named "wpa_supplicant" with this in it :

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="ssid"
    psk="password"
}
```

Should i rename sd card to something specific?
Is using characters in ssid like "áéĺ" etc. bad?

Comment: a) I thought the file was `wpa_supplicant.conf` not `wpa_supplicant`- b) does Kali linux even look for those file on boot - just because raspberry pi OS does, doesn't mean other OS do

Comment: yeah i saved it as wpa_supplicant.conf and i dont actually know (about that second thing) its my first time working with raspberry pi. I have bought cable (i hadnt one so i wanted to set it that way) so i am gonna try. But even if there was turned of ssh shouldnt it be shown as connected device?

Comment: to show as a connected (wireless) device, you assume putting `wpa_supplicant.conf` in the boot partition will work for kali as it does for raspberry pi OS - why? I can tell you not even  debian for pi (which is what raspberry pi OS is based on) will do that - as far as I am aware, adding wpa_supplicant.conf to the boot partition is a convenience added by the raspberry pi OS - you'll need to set up wifi credentials and ssh using a keyboard and screen

Comment: After you've booted, do `ssh` and `wpa_supplicant.conf` still exist in the boot partition? If so, then kali is not working like raspberry pi OS (which deletes those files in the boot partition)

Comment: Use the standard OS.  kali is for experts and you will find little support.